# Extract columns using int array values as index from a data

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to fetch the columns from a dataframe called as diabetes_test which has 8 columns.

```
model=c(6,7,8)
```

`diabetes_test[, as.vector(model)]` gives output as `6 7 8`, while `diabetes_test[, c(6,7,8)]` gives the following output.

[image]

This is the desired output which I want, but not able to despite converting the model to a vector. `diabetes_test[, c(model)]` or `diabetes_test[, unlist(model)]` doesn't work either.

What is more confusing is, that it works when I want to extract the rows but not column, i.e. `diabetes_test[model]` gives me the 6th, 7th and 8th rows, but `diabetes_test[,model]` doesn't give me the 6th, 7th and the 8th column.

[image]

Comment: diabetes_test[, model] does not work?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Strangely, while diabetes_test[model] works for getting rows

Comment: Try `diabetes_test[,model,with=FALSE]`. Read also this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html and the help page of the `data.table` package `?data.table`.

Comment: wow, that works. I have been banging my head in the wall for this since a long time. could you please post this as an answer? so that i can accept it

Comment: Hey, could you please post this as an answer which I can accept? Or i will have to do it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following worked for me `diabetes_test[,model,with=FALSE]`. Read https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html and the help page of the data.table package `?data.table`